# mongodb $match с использованием даты

Tags: node.js, mongodb

В mongodb отфильтровать записи за сегодня можно, например, так:

```
{
    stamp: {
        $gte: ISODate('2019-07-19T00:00:00.000Z'),
        $lt: ISODate('2019-07-19T23:59:59.999Z')
    }
}
```

А как это сделать через nodejs передав критерии из переменной?

Пробовал вот так:

```
сonst criteria = {
    "stamp": {
        "$gte":{"$date":"2019-07-19T00:00:00.000Z"},
        "$lt":{"$date":"2019-07-19T23:59:59.999Z"}
    }
};

const pipeline = [
    {
        $match: criteria
    }
]

collection.aggregate(request)
```

не выдает ничего

Comment: Посмотрите пример. https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb_find.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так работает:

```
сonst criteria = {
    "stamp": {
        $gte: new Date('2019-07-19T00:00:00.000Z'),
        $lt: new Date('2019-07-19T23:59:59.999Z')
    }
};
```